# perl eval throwing blank exception

Tags: exception, perl

I am updating a few records in database. And all the processing is done in eval block.
The problem is that even if the records are successfully updated , I still see a exception being raised.

To debug the exception, I tried printing it using Data Dumper but the exception is blank.

Can any one please help me identify what is this error and why is it thrown every time ?

Environment Details (Perl 5.8 and Unix SUSE)

Dump from Data Dumper:

```
$VAR1 = '
';
```

I am using various internal APIs, to update these records.. so I have modified my code to look similar:

```
      sub main{
        eval{
         DB->updateRecord($value)
        };
        if($@){
             Mail->SendMail(__PACKAGE__,$@):
        }
       }

       package DB;
       sub updateRecord{
             my ($self , $value) = @_;
             my $query = "update set column_value = $value ..<update query> ";
            API->processQuery($query );
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the code here so we might be able to shed some light on the situation?

Comment: Without some code your question will get downvoted and possibly closed.  Please read the [faq] and [ask].

Comment: That dump is not blank, it contains a newline character, which is not considered to be false/empty.

Comment: Is your SQL query really unquoted, or is that just a typo?

Comment: it is just a typo it is quoted.

Comment: Is it also a typo that you left out the `sub` keyword?

Comment: Thnx for comments TLP... I have fixed all the typos. Since I modified the code after copying it here. I think I did some really bad editing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does your code `use warnings;`?

The symptom your describing indicated that in your code you are passing `die` the string `"\n"`. My guess would be that in your source you have a line that is trying to die with an error message but your error message was not initialized. It could be something like

```
my $error;
if (some_test()) {
    $error = 'Some String';
}
if (some_other_test()) {
    die "$error\n";
}
```

If `some_test()` passes but `some_other_test()` fails the die will report an error containing only a new line. It would also emit an warning if warnings are enabled.

Another possibility is a typo. If you don't `use strict;` the error variable might not be correct.

```
my $error = 'Some String';
if ($error) {
    #note the typo (transposed ro to or)
    die "$erorr\n";
}
```

Without `use strict;` this can be an easy mistake to miss.

Comment: It's actual possible for `eval` to clobber `$@`. (Fixed in 5.14 or 5.16.) If you knew that and figured it was more likely to be a different error, and you were right, wow!

Comment: @ikegami, the symptom was `$@ = "\n"` the cobber bug in Perl would typically leave `$@ = undef`. If your interested my logic was along the lines of to get "\n" in $@ someone probably effectively called `die "\n";`, but they probably didn't write that. So what would a typical mistake be to produce it? It's probably an uninitialized value interpolated into the string. Which leads to, why no warning?